# Change Left Image in FINISH_UNPAGE with NSIS?

Tags: nsis

Is possible change the image bmp in left... only in the FINISH_UNPAGE?
Thanks!

The example is:

[image: finish]

I need change the image only in this window "FINISH_UNPAGE".

Answer (score 1):

`MUI_UNWELCOMEFINISHPAGE_BITMAP` is usually all you need but you can just overwrite the bitmap file at the right time to change it.

```
!include MUI2.nsh
InstallDir $temp\example
!define MUI_UNWELCOMEFINISHPAGE_BITMAP "${NSISDIR}\Contrib\Graphics\Wizard\orange.bmp" ; This sets the image for the uninstallers Welcome AND Finish pages which is usually what you want.

!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FINISH
!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_WELCOME
!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_CONFIRM
!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_INSTFILES
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_PRE un.overrideunfinishbmp
!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_FINISH
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"

Function un.overrideunfinishbmp 
File "/oname=$PLUGINSDIR\modern-wizard.bmp" "${NSISDIR}\Contrib\Graphics\Wizard\nullsoft.bmp"
FunctionEnd

Section
SetOutPath "$InstDir"
WriteUninstaller "$InstDir\Uninstall.exe"
SectionEnd

Section Uninstall
Delete "$InstDir\Uninstall.exe"
RMDir "$InstDir"
SectionEnd
```